# Logical Replication stops working on Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, replication

I have two databases in different servers instances. Each database has the same amount of tables (108). Tables in my Operation database have all the data. Tables in DWH is completely empty. I built logical replication on Postgres between these two databases and tables. It was built even it did the initial loading between databases. It works lets say 20 minutes without any problem. After it suddenly stops and nothing is changing in the DWH any update, insert or other operations. What can be the problem ? I have built many times logical replication but never experienced this kind of thing.

Comment: Long running transactions on the publisher, perhaps.

Comment: Look in the server log file.  Probably on the replica side, but check both.

Comment: Long running transactions How can I prevent this maybe I have to increase the number of replication slots yes ? Maybe it can not load these amount of transactions